# How to get flexbox to fill remaining height properly in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

[image: screencap near full size]
[image: screencap of image squashing up as viewport shrinks]
There are so many questions people have asked and answered about getting a flexbox div to fill the remaining height, but they are all slightly disappointing.

I want to get a div to fill the screen height responsively, and to make the background green. I don't want to have to tell the css the height of anything, I just want it to fill up the available space.

Every solution I've seen reverts to specifying a height at some stage, and I don't want to do that because it means either scroll-bars or white spaces some of the time.

Just colouring the body background seems even more complicated in Angular and I don't want to mess with my theme if I can help it, but this would also be a way to achieve what I want. It just feels like there should be a way to just tell a div to fill the rest of the browser window and it's really bugging me.

HTML:

```
<div flex layout="column" class="outer">
    <div class="top">
        <span class="left-spacer"></span>
    <span class="page-header">
        HOME
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="middle-constrained">
            <img src="{{image}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Bungee+Shade');


.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #009999;
    min-height: 100%;

}

.top {
    flex: 1;
    order: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 33%;
}

.middle {
    flex: 8;
    order: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 33%;
}

.bottom {
    order: 3;
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: 33%;
    background-color: #009999;
}

.left-spacer {
    flex: 7;
    background-color: #009999;
}

.page-header {
    padding: 0px;
    background-color:  #009999;
    flex: 1;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
    font-size: 2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #E1E3F3;
 }

 .middle {
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
 }

 .middle-constrained {
    flex: 1;
 }

 img {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

I also have an Angular Material Toolbar component at the top of my webpage.

Comment: not sure which element you want to fill the page... like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqvYJN

Comment: Exactly like that, except with a toolbar at the top. It would be possible to make the toolbar say 3vh and .outer 97vh, but the vh property seems to mess with the img scaling when I resize the browser window.

Comment: doing what you said makes the page behave the same way as far as I can tell. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/WENaaN if that doesn't work, can you make a demo demonstrating the scaling problem?

Comment: Yep - sorry ignore the bit about the toolbar. I can't really make a codepen that's any different to yours - the only difference is I'm using the angular-cli dev environment. Have you tried it with an actual image? I will add screencaps of the image squashing when it resizes to the question.

Comment: looks like you're using `height: 100%; width: 100%` on the `img` which will make the image stretch if it doesn't fit the size of the containing element exactly. I might use a background image with a padding value that matches the ratio of the image (divide the height by the width and multiply by 100 and use that as a % for `padding-bottom`). here's an example https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/rzNqEw

Comment: Why don't you just make the body background green and the image 100% width, why do you need a spacer after the image?

Comment: I was under the impression the body tag was overridden by the angular routing, but I was using background-color when I tested it, not background. That does indeed work.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't get why you can't get a div to fill the screen without specifying a height!